# Ler o txt e retornar ele todo em uma String em Java

Tags: java, arquivo

Possuo esse código para ler um `txt`e gostaria de depois retornar uma *string* com o `txt`todo copiado , porém esse algoritmo ele só ler as linhas e vai mostrando como faço para retornar todo o conteúdo que ele leu em uma variável *string*?

```
  public static void main (String[]args){
      String linha = null;

      try{
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/algoritmo.txt"));
         while(br.ready()){
             linha= br.readLine();
            System.out.println(linha);

         }
         br.close();
      }catch(IOException ioe){
         ioe.printStackTrace();

      }
      System.out.println());}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É bem mais simples que isso:

```
System.out.println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("c:/algoritmo.txt"))));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/ReadAll.java).

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)).